# Push faces together

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create pleats on a garment I'm trying to model. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I'm not clear how to explain this...I want to "push" the selected faces together, the way we create pleats. If you consider each of those faces to be cloth, I want to fold them inwards. Each pair of face forms a V as you can see. I want these faces to come closer, with the edge connecting them acting as a fold edge.

How do I go about this?

Answer: NoviceInDisguise's comment below was the answer: Scale:

[image]

Comment: Scale along the Y axis? I am not sure what you are asking . . .

Comment: Thanks, it was that simple! I updated the question with your comment as as the answer, and posted the output of how I wanted it to look..

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise You could post that as an answer to take this off of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Scale`.

Press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> and scale as desired.